# can't create kubernetes cluster on gcp with Owner role

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-iam

I'm trying to create an Kubernetes cluster on GCP with Terraform, and I get

`Error: googleapi: Error 403: Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.networks.get' permission for 'projects/projects-test/global/networks/default'., forbidden`

I'm using an owner permissions account to perform that, the same Terraform script work 2 weeks ago. Is it any change that I missing to process that ?

Comment: Is it your own organisation or this one of your company? Do you use a shared VPC?

Comment: You think you are using credentials with the `owner` role but you are not. The first step is to figure out which credential you are using. Your post does not show how you setup ADC (gcloud auth application default login, GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, etc) or how you are authorizing the Terraform HCL. Edit your post once with details. Error messages by themselves are usually not helpful.

Comment: I had the same error on google console

Comment: I'm using the default VPC @guillaume blaquiere

Comment: Can you check the permission of the service account `service-<ProjectNumber>@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com` (in the UI when you include the Google-provided role grants)? What do you have?

Comment: i had `security-center-api.iam.gserviceaccount.com` and `service-networking.iam.gserviceaccount.com` as service account

Comment: This might be an issue with accessing VPC network, try adding `roles/compute.networkUser` to the account.

Comment: the issue was resolved by re-enabling the kubernetes engine API thanks for your help